# How to trigger a css animation with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a css animation trigger with javascript.I have made the animation with `@keyframes` and it works. Dose anyone know how to do this without stuff like jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
/* Animations */

@keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}
```

Comment: you need to create another CSS that uses your keyframe animation, like `.animated {animation: party 2s infinite}` and then with JS you add this class to the element you want to animate

Comment: You can add a class that adds the animation property and there's also an `animate` method for html elements to animate some stuff https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think adding `class` is a healthy way to do it.

Check the example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/zYBgjXN

```js
document.getElementById('box').classList.add('active-animation');
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.box.active-animation {
  animation: party 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></di>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier than you think, you only need to call the animation, like this:

This is a example to trigger with a button

```js
function party(){
  document.body.style.animation = 'party 2.5s infinite linear';
}
```

```css
body{
background-color: purple;
}

@keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body id="bd">
    <button onclick="party()">Press Me!</button>
  </body>


</html>
```

I wait this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `animation` property of the element you are trying to animate, like this.

```js
// sets the css animation property
const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
spinner.style.animation = "spin 3s linear infinite";
```

```css
/* gives the div element a border and size */
#spinner {
  border: 15px solid black;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* no animation property is inserted here */
}

/* spin animation */
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- div element to animate -->
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.style.animation = "party 5s infinite";
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes party{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    10% {background-color: orange;}
    20% {background-color: yellow;}
    30% {background-color: green;}
    40% {background-color: blue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;} 
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```